# Minecraft item sorter not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

[image]

[image]

Edit: I tried having the hoppers face the comparators, it made no difference

As you can see in the picture, I am trying to make an item sorter, but once I put the items in it seems to work for like 30 seconds but keeps breaking for seemingly no reason. The hoppers next to the comparators each have 44 sticks named "filter", with 1 of the item I'm trying to sort (gold in this case).

Comment: i do think the hoppers need to face comparators, but i dont remember. worth a try

Comment: What *order* are the items placed within the hopper? The item you want to sort must be in the *first* slot.

Comment: Yea, i have 1, 41, 1 1 1

Comment: can you post screenshots with increased brightness so people can see what is happening better?

Comment: You can also click on the pictures to see them in greater detail. It seems like everything important is clearly visible. I just followed the traditional design, the only difference being I would like to have it vertical like this, which doesnt seem to work? Could it have something to do with the torch also powering the chest?

Answer (score -2):

Nope: chests ain't powerable and dont conduct redstone signal, unlike barrels.

Comment: The torches power the block above them. Doesn't matter if the chest can get powered or not